# MYSQL where clause, where one timestamp field less then another subtract n days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two timestamp fields in mysql table - expire_at and last_check. I need query to get records where last_check < (expire_at - 7 days)

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause would be:

```
where last_check < expire_at - interval 7 day
```